# How to use Elasticsearch json-like query directly in Kibana Visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

Say I have following json-like Elasticsearch Query About an aggregation:

```
POST /testi/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "nested_properties": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "bill"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filtered_by_attribute": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "bill.code": 2
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "avg_coded_string_2": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "bill.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I use this query directly to create A Visualization in Kibana?
I didn't find any way except `kibana Query` and `Lucene Query`.